# javascript input a specific character once

Tags: javascript

i made a function where you can only input alphabets , @ and ( . ) period.
how can i set that i can only input the "@" sign once and after that it will automatically add "email.com" . for example i input my email like "stackoverflow" and after i hit "@" it will automatically add "email.com" and that "@" can only be inputted once..

here's my code

```
function fnEmailAlpha(e)
{
    var key;
    if(window.event)
       key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
    else
       key = e.which;                  //Firefox
    if ((key>96 && key<123) || (key>64 && key<90) || key==46 || key == 64 || key == 95)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: possible solution: if(e.shiftKey && key == 50){if(this.value.indexOf('@') !== -1) {return} this.value += '@email.com'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validate(textbox) {
            //Handle Keycodes to return without action in case of arrow keys, backspace etc.
            var email = 'email.com';
            var val = textbox.value;
            var ind = textbox.value.indexOf('@');
            if (ind > -1)
                textbox.value = val.substring(0, ind + 1) + email;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frm" name="frm">
        <input type="text" id="txtInput" name="txtInput" onkeyup ="validate(this)" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh thank you very much . :)  , but i can still input '@' as much as i want.

Comment: I have fixed this. However there are many other things you can do to improve the code :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to validate for an email id, then I suggest using a [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

What you could do is:

```
var reg=/^[a-zA-Z]+[\@]{1}[a-zA-Z]+[\.]{1}[a-zA-Z]+$/ig;
if(document.getElementById('email').value.match(reg)!=null)
{
   alert('Match!');
}
```

Comment: Then what’s your advice on the original question? Should he still *also* restrict the user from typing `@` more than once, and fill in the template of an email for them, or is that behavior a bad idea for some reason?

Comment: where should i put that. sorry i'm just new in programming :(

Comment: He could use an `onkeyup` event trigger to check on each character entry but that would be pointless since the `regex` takes care of matching for more than one `@`. @user2789695 to answer your question, the code should be placed in a function called on `onblur` of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

[if you need JavaScript solution](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_validate_email):

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}
```

or if you are using HTML5

```
 E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```